# Is there really no way to know if you are accelerating or you are in gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, time-dilation, equivalence-principle

So any gravitational field will have a gradient, no? But an accelerating object does not experience any gradient of force. So you should be able to tell if you are in gravity or accelerating by measurement. Right? Is it even possible to experience constant gravity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the lay explanation of the equivalence principle wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172739/)

Comment: "any gravitational field will have a gradient, no?". No. A constant and uniform gravitational field, by definition, does not change in space or time. This may not be physically realistic, but the equivalence principle is not restricted to physically realistic gravitational fields.

Comment: Apply some force in the opposite direction to the apparent acceleration. If you feel the latter is changing then it was a true acceleration, if not it was gravity.