# falling in a gravitional field

Tags: newtonian-gravity

It is often stated that masses fall at the same rate towards the Earth at the same rate (barring things like friction), and this seems to be quoted as the Equivalence Principle. Is this statement correct? I was thinking that the force of $M$ on $m$ causes $m$ to accelerate towards $M$ with $a_m = GM/r^2$, and similarly the force of $m$ on $M$ to accelerate towards $m$ with acceleration $a_M = Gm/r^2$. Isn't the relative acceleration $a_m + a_M = G(M+m)/r^2$, and if you're stationary on $M$ it will appear that $m$ is accelerating towards you with an acceleration that depends slightly on $m$? If correct, I assume the correct statement should be something more like "objects of different masses fall in a *constant* gravitational field at the same rate"? (It may even be that it is?)

Comment: The equivalence principle is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle

Comment: Thanks, but there is the comment "During the Apollo 15 mission in 1971, astronaut David Scott showed that Galileo was right: acceleration is the same for all bodies subject to gravity on the Moon, even for a hammer and a feather." that suggests that the equivalence principle is about objects falling in the gravitational field of a mass. I don't think this is strictly true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalence principle question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52593/)

Comment: Seems quite different?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/2451

Comment: That is correct and, at the same time, irrelevant for the equivalence principle. The reduced mass is a kinematic term that you can already observe in collisions and that appears in all force interactions, as well. The usual formulation of the equivalence principle is for small test masses, which do not modify the reduced mass sufficiently to be of interest. For a 1kg hammer and Earth's $6\times 10^{24}kg$ that a very good approximation.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I am asking.

Comment: Correct - falling towards the earth at the same rate is something that is often attributed to Galileo, and described as [Galileo's Leaning Tower of Pisa experiment (1589)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_experiment).